# Simple HTACCESS question to redirect IP to domain name

Tags: .htaccess

I'm looking to redirect an IP address to a domain name using HTACCESS.  So anytime the IPaddress.com/subdir1/page1.html shows up it'll redirect to domainname.com/subdir1/page1.html

I've tried this with NO LUCK:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^123\.45\.67\.89
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Because it ONLY redirects the main IP address to the main domain,  not subdirectory ips to subdirectory domains

Thank you
Jeff

Answer (score 1):

Pretty old now, but maybe you meant RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR}

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you probably just forgot a `^` and maybe a `$` or two... No reason this shouldn't work:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^123\.45\.67\.89$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```